# Calculate the Arc that joins two arcs from a known tangent

Tags: geometry

I have two separated arcs ($AB$ and $CD$) and I want to calculate a new arc ($BP$) so that:

- The arc $BP$'s start tangent must be the same of the arc $AB$'s end tangent.
- The arc $BP$'s end tangent must be the same to the tangent of a point lying on the arc $CD$.
- The arc $AB$'s end tangent is fixed.
- The new arc ($BP$) must not intersect with arc $CD$

Is there a way to calculate the green arc ($BP$)?

Thanks.

The problem:

[image: The problem]

Comment: Your final point is somewhat vague. What do you mean, not intersect?

Comment: Please have a look at this photo: http://i.imgur.com/E5c8HcB.png

Comment: Yes, I guess that is taken care of by my answer. Where do you have a problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of curves of that kind. One way to do that would be to consider the curve as $$ y^2= mx^2+nx $$
$$ 2y \frac{dy}{dx}= 2mx+n $$

From the second equation your can get 2 simultaneous equations in m and n for the two points B and C.

Hence for the 2 points B and C you get two equations.

The resulting curve would be that of a hyperbola.

As for the final property of non intersection, you would need to know the character of the given curves.